# Get all parameters from a doctrinemongodb document

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm working with Doctrine 2.0 MongoDB/Symfony 2 and I asked myself if there is some way to get all parameters from a document. For example: document User has: username, mail, gender. I'm looking for a function that returns "username", "mail", "gender".

Comment: Haven't used it myself but http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/metadata-drivers.html#getting-classmetadata-instances (26.4) looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a query with Doctrine ODM with: **createQueryBuilder**, **find**, **findAll** and so on, you obtain a whole result with all the fields. In your example, you can obtain its values through getters.